# iOS Autolayout height is ambiguous for UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

[image: ambiguous warning]

```
Height is ambiguous for UILabel (topCommentLabel)
Height and vertical position is ambiguous for UIView (commentContainerView)
```

In the tableview cell using

> _tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

I have one containerView with 3 Labels in it and I want the Label's content hold up the containerView

here is my constriants

```
{// comment area
        [self.commentContainerView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.left.right.mas_equalTo(self.contentLabel);
            make.top.mas_equalTo(self.contentLabel.mas_bottom).mas_offset(10);
        }];
        
        [self.topCommentLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.left.right.mas_equalTo(0);
        }];
        
        [self.bottomCommentLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.mas_equalTo(self.topCommentLabel.mas_bottom).mas_offset(0);
            make.left.right.mas_equalTo(0);
        }];
        
        [self.readAllCommentLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.mas_equalTo(self.bottomCommentLabel.mas_bottom).mas_offset(0);
            make.left.bottom.mas_equalTo(0);
        }];
    }
```

the view displays normal but I got the ambiguous warning

Why this warning happen and How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `vertical hugging priority`. If you super view's height constraint with its content, it will need at least 1 element, in this example is a `Label` with higher (252) or lower (250) priority with others. Setting `hugging priority` to one of your label to ignore this layout warning.

Comment: When I add 
[self.topCommentLabel setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
to topCommentLabel still got the warning do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: @HarrisHan actually you should set it to `UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow ` bro